# How to run GHCi in command line like a regular shell command

Tags: haskell

Is there any way I can run GHCi on command line like a regular command in shell?

For example: :browse in GHCi - list all the function for specific module.

but I want to run it on shell, e.g.:  `ghci --browse "MyModule"`
which lists all the functions for the module

I know hoogle can run it on shell, e.g: hoogle Monad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to pipe in the commands via standard input. In Bash this can be done nicely with a “here-string”:

```
$ ghci <<< ':t reverse'
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> reverse :: [a] -> [a]
Prelude> Leaving GHCi.
```

Use verbosity 0 to avoid all the greeting stuff:

```
$ ghci -v0 <<< ':t reverse'
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```